# How do I move my Outlook mac files to Ms outlook 2010?

Tags: macos, ms-office, windows, import

How can I move all my emails including the mailboxes from Outlook mac to Ms outlook 2010?

Answer (score 1):

This depends a little bit how the outlooks are connected to the mail server.

When you use an Exchange Server, you don'T have to do anything. You just configure to keep all mails online in the server. Then you connect with Win Outlook and can access your email.
Another option is to exports all mails from MAC Outlook. And open this export in Win Outlook.

ciao
ryder